# Python beautifulsoup AttributeError

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get some image url using python beautifulsoup from html content.

My HTML Content :

```
<div id="photos" class="tab rel-photos multiple-photos">
   <span id="watch-this" class="classified-detail-buttons">
   <span id="c_id_10832265:c_type_202:watch_this">
   <a href="/watchlist/classified/baby-items/10832265/1/" id="watch_this_logged" data-require-auth="favoriteAd" data-tr-event-name="dpv-add-to-favourites">
   <i class="fa fa-fw fa-star-o"></i></a></span>
   </span>
   <span id="thumb1" class=" image">
      <a href="https://images.dubizzle.com/v1/files/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmbiI6ImYzYWdrZm8xcDBlai1EVUJJWlpMRSIsInciOlt7ImZuIjoiNWpldWk3cWZ6aWU2MS1EVUJJWlpMRSIsInMiOjUwLCJwIjoiY2VudGVyLGNlbnRlciIsImEiOjgwfV19.s1GmifnZr0_Bx4HG8RTR4puYcxN0asqAmnBvSpIExEI/image;p=main"
         id="a-photo-modal-view:263986810"
         rel="photos-modal"
         target="_new"
         onClick="return dbzglobal_event_adapter(this);">
         <div style="background-image:url(https://images.dubizzle.com/v1/files/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmbiI6ImYzYWdrZm8xcDBlai1EVUJJWlpMRSIsInciOlt7ImZuIjoiNWpldWk3cWZ6aWU2MS1EVUJJWlpMRSIsInMiOjUwLCJwIjoiY2VudGVyLGNlbnRlciIsImEiOjgwfV19.s1GmifnZr0_Bx4HG8RTR4puYcxN0asqAmnBvSpIExEI/image;p=main);"></div>
      </a>
   </span>
   <ul id="thumbs-list">
      <li>
         <span id="thumb2" class="image2">
            <a href="https://images.dubizzle.com/v1/files/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmbiI6Imtmc3cxMWgzNTB2cTMtRFVCSVpaTEUiLCJ3IjpbeyJmbiI6IjVqZXVpN3FmemllNjEtRFVCSVpaTEUiLCJzIjo1MCwicCI6ImNlbnRlcixjZW50ZXIiLCJhIjo4MH1dfQ.Wo2YqPdWav8shtmyVO2AdisHmLX-ZLDAiskLPAmTSPU/image;p=main" id="a-photo-modal-view:263986811" rel="photos-modal" target="_new" onClick="return dbzglobal_event_adapter(this);" >
               <div style="background-image:url(https://images.dubizzle.com/v1/files/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmbiI6Imtmc3cxMWgzNTB2cTMtRFVCSVpaTEUiLCJ3IjpbeyJmbiI6IjVqZXVpN3FmemllNjEtRFVCSVpaTEUiLCJzIjo1MCwicCI6ImNlbnRlcixjZW50ZXIiLCJhIjo4MH1dfQ.Wo2YqPdWav8shtmyVO2AdisHmLX-ZLDAiskLPAmTSPU/image;p=thumb_retina);"></div>
            </a>
         </span>
      </li>
      <li id="thumbnails-info">
         4 Photos
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div id="photo-count">
      4 Photos - Click to enlarge
   </div>
</div>
```

My python code :

```
images = soup.find("div", {"id": ["photos"]}).find_all("a")
for image in images:
    
    sk = image.get("href").replace("p=main","p=thumb_retina",1)
    print(sk)
```

But i'm getting error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/evilslab/Documents/Websites/www.futurepoint.dev.cc/dobuyme/SCRAPE/boats.py", line 47, in <module>
    images = soup.find("div", {"id": ["photos"]}).find_all("a")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

How i can get only the url from a href tag ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me, more completely (given your HTML as `html_doc`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
images = soup.find("div", {"id": ["photos"]}).find_all("a")
for image in images:
    print(image['href'].replace("p=main","p=thumb_retina",1))
```

However your problem is that the text returned by `requests` from URL is **not** the same as the HTML sample you give. Despite your attempt to supply a random user agent, the server returns:

```
<li>You\'re a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.</li>\n                        <li>You\'ve disabled JavaScript in your web browser.</li>\n                        <li>A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running. Additional information is available in this <a title=\'Third party browser plugins that block javascript\' href=\'http://ds.tl/help-third-party-plugins\' target=\'_blank\'>support article</a>.</li>\n                    </ul>\n                </div>\n                <p class="we-could-be-wrong" >\n                    We could be wrong, and sorry about that! Please complete the CAPTCHA below and we’ll get you back on dubizzle right away.
```

Since the CAPTCHA is intended to prevent scraping, I suggest respecting the admin's wishes and not scraping it. Maybe there's an API?

Comment: page = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent': user_agent.random})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

Comment: url = "https://dubai.dubizzle.com/classified/baby-items/nursery-furniture-accessories/bassinets-cradles-rockers/2020/3/16/baby-sleepyhead-deluxe-2/?back=L2NsYXNzaWZpZWQvYmFieS1pdGVtcy8%3D&pos=2"

Comment: So that means, No way to do that ?

Comment: What you think about fake ip

Comment: They blacklisted my ip then ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for item in soup.find_all('span'):
    try:
        link = item.find_all('a', href=True)[0].attrs.get('href', None)
    except IndexError:
        continue
    else:
        print(link)
```

output

```
/watchlist/classified/baby-items/10832265/1/
/watchlist/classified/baby-items/10832265/1/
https://images.dubizzle.com/v1/files/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmbiI6ImYzYWdrZm8xcDBlai1EVUJJWlpMRSIsInciOlt7ImZuIjoiNWpldWk3cWZ6aWU2MS1EVUJJWlpMRSIsInMiOjUwLCJwIjoiY2VudGVyLGNlbnRlciIsImEiOjgwfV19.s1GmifnZr0_Bx4HG8RTR4puYcxN0asqAmnBvSpIExEI/image;p=main
https://images.dubizzle.com/v1/files/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmbiI6Imtmc3cxMWgzNTB2cTMtRFVCSVpaTEUiLCJ3IjpbeyJmbiI6IjVqZXVpN3FmemllNjEtRFVCSVpaTEUiLCJzIjo1MCwicCI6ImNlbnRlcixjZW50ZXIiLCJhIjo4MH1dfQ.Wo2YqPdWav8shtmyVO2AdisHmLX-ZLDAiskLPAmTSPU/image;p=main
```

Comment: Same error. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/evilslab/Documents/Websites/www.futurepoint.dev.cc/dobuyme/SCRAP/boats.py", line 48, in <module>
    for image in soup.find("div", {"id": ["photos"]}).find_all("a"):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: I changed my answer give it a try. Else please send the url, because from the html in the question I can`t replicate your error

Comment: url = "https://dubai.dubizzle.com/classified/baby-items/nursery-furniture-accessories/bassinets-cradles-rockers/2020/3/16/baby-sleepyhead-deluxe-2/?back=L2NsYXNzaWZpZWQvYmFieS1pdGVtcy8%3D&pos=2"